# How can I know about the local SQL Server on my system ( windows 7 )

Tags: sql-server

How do I know whether I have a local SQL Server on my system? If there is what are the login details to the local SQL Server ? I have a windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

> how do i know whether i have a local mssql server on my system.

Check in Program Files, for a folder called Microsoft SQL Server - assuming a default install.

Answer (score 1):

- In Administrative Tools\Services look for `SQl Server`, `SQL Server Browser`.
- Login as an administrator to your machine.
- If you do not have Management Studio, you can download Express version it from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en). It will auto auth with your system credentials and show you the current databases on your system.